# Is there a reference to all Windows "errorlevel" by command?

Tags: command-line, script, batch

Is there a reference to all Windows "errorlevel" by command?  Looking for a page that defines all error levels, by command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here http://wiki.fdos.org/Main/ExitCodes is an old list that covers many typical command line commands

here http://www.computerhope.com/doserror.htm is a list of the most typical error messages with an explanation

and here http://en.kioskea.net/faq/sujet-2347-error-codes-in-windows is a more complete list of windows error codes, some are surfaced as exit codes and some are not.

Comment: The first link is dead by now (Checked at Sep 17, 2020).

Answer (score 0):

Windows has a built-in reference for the ERRORLEVEL error codes. Just get the ERRORLEVEL and run `net helpmsg YOUR_ERROR_CODE`.